# Past simple or past perfect?

Tags: verb-usage

Which is correct: "Yesterday my sister read about a soldier who ***was accidently killed/had accidently been killed*** by another soldier."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any other context or mention of other actions, either of your sentences are correct and understandable.

> Yesterday my sister read about a soldier who was killed accidently by another soldier.
>   Yesterday my sister read about a soldier who had been killed accidently by another soldier.

Comment: If this is at the answer you're looking for please mark it as "accepted" so other answerers won't spend time on it.

Comment: Could you tell me, please, how I can mark it as "accepted"?

Comment: There is a checkmark on the left hand side of the answer, click that.